# I got sick of my boss’s moaning and told him he could stick the job

Tags: meaning-in-context, idiomatic-language

> I got sick of my boss’s moaning and told him he could stick the job.

What's the meaning of 'stick' here?

One of the definition is :

<informal: from Oxford dictionary>
used to express angry dismissal

: he told them they could stick the job—he didn't want it anyway

Comment: Check Cambridge Dictionary.

Comment: I prefer answers from people to ones from dictionaries.

Comment: The rules of this site state that questions which can be answered from a dictionary are off-topic and liable to be closed.

Comment: Maybe so, but you almost first need to know that 'stick' in this instance is a redaction of where he might like to stick it ;)

Comment: It's a short form of a vulgar expression "stick [something] up your arse". [see here](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stick+it+up+your+arse)

Comment: 'Stick' as in 'put'. I stuck my finger into an ants' nest.

Comment: For me, the Cambridge Dictionary does not provide a suitable definition.  "If you tell someone to stick something or where they can stick something, it means that you do not want to keep that thing:".   Technically correct.  But Cambridge definition does not address the aggressive nature of "stick it up your ___".  Or that "stick it" is a shortened version of that phrase.  Or that "shove it" is a synonymous variation.  The sorts of things important to a learner.  Seems to me that this question should not be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an idiomatic, shortened form of a vulgar expression:

"stick this job up your ass" (or other orifice)

It means, "I'm giving you this job (refusing it)", in an aggressive, antagonistic way.